# Toggle Open for rows after a particular class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

I am trying to toggle open rows after a particular class. The current script hides all the rows after the class "toggle-open". But what I am looking at is, only hide the rows starting from the adjacent row till the row above the next class "toggle-open".
Any thoughts on how to achieve this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/EBtPP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap each group between `<tbody>` tags, you can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EBtPP/2/

```
$('td.toggle-open').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr:has(td.toggle-open)').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. it worked fine, but the problem is, the data is being populated from the server side using .Net, and its hard to distinguish the groups so they cant use tbody to group it... is there any other alternate way to achieve this..